# Lie bracket of vector fields on $R^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, manifolds, lie-groups

Compute the Lie bracket$$\Big[-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big]$$

on $R^2$

Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the Lie bracket?

Comment: [X,Y]f=(XY-YX)f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that this is what you want, but I think that
$$\begin{align}
\Big[-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big] &= \left(-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \\
&= -y\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  +y\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \\ 
&= \dots
\end{align}
$$

Use the product rule on the last part:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + x \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @user114952: You are welcome.

Comment: doesn't it simplify to $-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ assuming we are dealing with a $C^\infty$ structure?

Comment: @Seth: Yes, it will simplify quite a bit. Would we get $-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}$?

Comment: We should get $-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

Comment: @Seth: OK, you are probably right :)

Comment: Yes I agree with the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
[−y∂/∂x+x∂/∂y,∂/∂x]=(−y∂/∂x+x∂/∂y)(∂/∂x)−(∂/∂x)(−y∂/∂x+x∂/∂y)= - ∂/∂y
```